# How do I delete a scene in Scrivener?

Tags: tools, scrivener

I purchased Scrivener a few weeks ago. As I was messing around with it trying to get a hang of how to use it I accidentally added too many scenes in one chapter. How do I delete these scenes?

Answer (score 3):

Right click on Windows, or two fingered click on a Mac. From there, select Move to Trash. It'll then stay in that document's specific trash folder. You can retrieve scenes out of the document's specific trash until you empty the trash. Some writers will only empty the trash at the end of a writing project.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the first scene by highlighting it (shift - click)
2. Go down all the scenes you want to select. - 
            **tip if there is too many it will lock up the Scrivner and the software will become unresponsive and then close itself; if that's the case delete your scenes in sections no more than maybe 50 at a time and empty trash after each selection has been deleted; this is after you reopen Scrivener).

   3. Go down to the final scene you want to delete hit shift and click this will highlight all the selected scenes.
   4. Then let go of shift key,
   5. Then click on the shift and delete button - this will move all scenes to the trash bin.
3. Make sure you haven't deleted anything you want and then right click your mouse and empty your trash.

I had my laptop in my suitcase and when I got to the hotel discovered that the computer had inserted hundreds (if not thousands of empty scenes in my manuscript).  The above process worked and it took about a half an hour because I couldn't do it all at one time.  Hope that helps!

Good Luck,
Pam Pearsall

Answer (score 0):

If each scene is a separate document, drag the unwanted ones to the trash folder.

Comment: There's also a trashcan icon at the top of the application that deletes documents.